# I have problem with sending a request to api in angular with submit button

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I can not sending request to api in onSubmit method

setting.service.ts

```
updateNumbers(number: PhoneNumbers): Observable<string> {
        return this.http.put<string>(`/napi/setting/numbers/, ${number.id}`, number);
    }
```

emergency-number.component.html

```
 <mat-card>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title>شماره همراه</h2>
                <div class="container" formArrayName="numbers" *ngFor="let number of numbers.controls; index as i">
                    <ng-container class="field" [formGroupName]="i">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>شماره همراه</mat-label>
                            <input type="tel" pattern="" matInput placeholder="09123456789" [formControlName]="numberFieldName" matTooltip="شماره همراه" autocomplete="on">
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="removeNumberField(i)" class="btn-delete">حذف</button>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
                <div><button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addNumberField()">اضافه کردن</button></div>
                <div><button class="action" type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!emergencyNumberGroup.valid">تایید</button></div>
            </mat-card>
```

./emergency-number.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControlOptions, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { BehaviorSubject, take } from 'rxjs';
import { PhoneNumbers } from '../../../models/phone-number.interface';
import { SettingService } from '../../../services/setting.service';
import { GlobalConstants } from '../../../shared/global-constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'farmonitor-emergency-number',
  templateUrl: './emergency-number.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emergency-number.component.scss'],
})
export class EmergencyNumberComponent implements OnInit {

    emergencyNumberGroup!: FormGroup;
    phoneNumbers: PhoneNumbers[];
    data: any;

constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private setService: SettingService,
    ) {
        this.phoneNumbers = [];
        this.link = ["/user-setting"];
        this.error$ = new BehaviorSubject("");
    }

onSubmit(): void {
        if(this.emergencyNumberGroup.invalid) {
            return;
        }
        
        // Send request to api server
        this.error$.next("");
        this.setService.updateNumbers(this.data.id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
            next: () => {
                if(this.data.id == true && this.data.number){
                    this.openSnackBar('شماره همراه با موفقیت ذخیره شد', 'بستن')
                }
            },
            error: (err: unknown) => {
                console.log(err);
                this.openSnackBar('شماره همراه ذخیره نشد', 'بستن')
            }
            });
    }

}
```

It should be open snackbar and show the response, but jut I have error in console mode in browser.
I got **ERROR TypeError: this.data is undefined.**

Comment: when you subscribe you received the response `...subscribe({next:(data:any)=>...})`. You need know what is the response, you can use console.log(data). See that there're **no** this.data

Comment: Where are you setting/ assigning value to data?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem!
In `emergency-number.component.html` at the first I had a mistake
my `emergency-number.component.html` code was:

```
<form [formGroup]="emergencyNumberGroup" (onSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

but in this way button can't connect the function
so it is the correct way:

```
<form [formGroup]="emergencyNumberGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

Answer (score 1):

To debug such issues, I would suggest adding *console.log()* statements to understand how the data is flowing across the functions.

From high-level view :

In service you's expecting *PhoneNumbers*

```
updateNumbers(number: PhoneNumbers): Observable<string> {
        return this.http.put<string>(`/napi/setting/numbers/, ${number.id}`, number);
    }
```

Whereas when you're calling this, you're passing *this.data.id* ref :  this.setService.updateNumbers(this.data.id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe()

So I would suggest changing your service input parameter to expect id instead of *PhoneNumbers*

```
updateNumbers(id:any): Observable<string> {
        return this.http.put<string>(`/napi/setting/numbers/, ${id}`, number);
    }
```